# Sublime Text 2 (Mac) - Custom build system for app engine

Tags: macos, build-automation, sublimetext2

I am trying to run an app engine build script through Sublime Text. It would be nice if I could see the log of `dev_appserver.py` during the build.

1. Created a shell script `run.sh`, which runs correctly from OS X's Terminal
2. Added the folder to `PATH`, in `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist`
3. Added a custom build system, and when invoke build, I get this error:

> ```
> [Errno 2] No such file or directory
> [cmd:  [u'./run.sh']]
> [dir:  /Users/..../src/ui]
> [path: ...:/Users/..../src]
> [Finished
> ```

The last path, `/Users/..../src`, is where `run.sh` resides.

Thanks.